# vk_api - отсутствует модуль, но он есть

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Установил модуль vk_api, вписал его в строку, и что же я вижу? Вот это я вижу:

> import vk_api
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vk_api'

Comment: Установил где? И вписал где? Если работаешь через pycharm то там надо было в него самого ставить. Попробуй применить внутри питона `pydoc modules`, глянь чего там есть

Comment: Верно, установил в py charm. Вставить - можно по подробнее?

Comment: @FiolDoll, внизу справа есть версия питона, используемая в текущем проекте. Если вы запустите какой-нибудь скрипт из проекта, то увидите в консоли какой питон запускался. Скорее всего, тот питон, куда вы ставили либу, и тот, что используется в текущем проекта, разные

Comment: Как вариант, создай новый проект, с галочкой "создать main.py". Потом копируешь свои .py файлы из старого в новый с заменой. Дальше выполняешь установку всех модулей уже в новом проекте. Установил в pycharm это внизу pycharm'а через Python console, так?

Comment: @Gh0sTG0 спасибо, последний способ помог

Comment: На всякий случай проверь что он там в main.py создает точку отладки (красный круг слева от кода), сними если есть. Я не уверен, мб сейчас это пофиксили, но где то с пол-года назад довольно долго пытался сообразить чезанафиг и почему программа встает после подобной манипуляции.